# javascript regex - Find a substring that is enclosed by a delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace all substrings `substr` that are enclosed by `$$`

For example, consider the string

```
some substr $$This substr is enclosed by the delimiter$$ another substr
```

should return

```
some substr $$This newsubstr is enclosed by the delimiter$$ another substr
```

What I have so far

```
(?:\${2})[^$]*(substr)[^$]*(?=\${2})
```

Edit: There are can more than one occurrence of the substring within the delimiter.

Comment: Can there be more than 1 occurrence?

Comment: of the substring? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first match all the substrings in between `$$` and then replace the other pattern only inside those matches.

```js
var s = "some substr $$This substr is enclosed by the delimiter$$ another substr";
var rxDollars = /\${2}[\s\S]*?\${2}/g;
var rxSubstr = /substr/g;
console.log(
  s.replace(rxDollars, function(match) { return match.replace(rxSubstr, "newsubstr"); })
);
```

Another modification to only run the replace on the text in between `$$`.

```js
var s = "some substr $$This substr is enclosed by the delimiter$$ another substr";
var rxDollars = /\${2}([\s\S]*?)\${2}/g;
var rxSubstr = /substr/g;
console.log(
  s.replace(rxDollars, function(match, group1) { return "$$" + group1.replace(rxSubstr, "newsubstr") + "$$"; })
);
```

You will need to adjust the `rxSubstr` regex to suit your real needs.

The `\${2}[\s\S]*?\${2}` pattern just matches two `$` chars, then any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the leftmost occurrence of double `$` chars.